# How to build an mp4 from a set of still images and an audio file in Java

Tags: java, mp4

I want to take a few still images and an audio file and turn them into an mp4 file. I am most familiar with java, so that is what I'd prefer to do the coding in. Is there any way to do this, or any library I should look into? I looked at mp4parser, but I couldn't see how to do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason to be doing this in java?  Something like ffmpeg can do this, but it's a command line tool.

Well, also a C++ library.  I guess there's a Java binding for it, too: https://code.google.com/p/jjmpeg/

For that matter, you could take a look at the ffmpeg source, figure out what they're doing here:

ffmpeg -start_number n -i test_%d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 test.mp4

Mux in some audio, and you're off. Anyhow, that's how I'd start out.  Perhaps someone else will chime in with better specifics.

Comment: The reason I was looking at java is because that's the language I'm most comfortable in, and I was looking to develop a gui from scratch that would make the process simpler. But if I can call this tool from a java class that would be perfect.